# Replace the contents of a vector with the values of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, replace

Well, I hope I explain it simple:

I have a matrix:

```
matrix(c("a","b","c",1,2,3), nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

with output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "1" 
[2,] "b"  "2" 
[3,] "c"  "3"
```

I have a vector, for example:

```
vector1 <- c("b", "a", "b", "c")
```

I want that another vector to pick the values associated of the matrix that appear on the vector. I mean, the final vector must be:

```
[1] 2 1 2 3
```

I can't figure it out at the moment.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `match` where 'm1' is the `matrix`

```
 match(vector1, m1[,1])
 #[1] 2 1 2 3
```

Or

```
 unname(setNames(as.numeric(m1[,2]), m1[,1])[vector1])
 #[1] 2 1 2 3
```